# Storing user login details in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, storage, android-database

I have implemented **Google** and **Facebook** login in my android app. Can anyone please tell me **how to store the user details in the app using shared preference for the same?**

Comment: Use Shared Preference

Comment: Using shared preferences you can store it see this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm.

Comment: How to implement shared preference ?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Try it. Ask about specific problems you encounter here.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference

**Write to Shared Preferences**

To write to a shared preferences file, create a SharedPreferences.Editor by calling **edit()** on your SharedPreferences.

Pass the keys and values you want to write with methods such as `putInt()` and `putString()`. Then call `commit()` to save the changes. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

**Read from Shared Preferences**

To retrieve values from a shared preferences file, call methods such as `getInt()` and `getString()`, providing the key for the value you want, and optionally a default value to return if the key isn't present. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

check example [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Answer (score 1):

Setting Value in Shared

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "raks");
 editor.putInt("idName", 1);
 editor.commit();
```

Fetching Value from Shared

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 

String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0);  //0 is the default value.
```

Here **MY_PREFS_NAME** is your File name

Answer (score 0):

You can SharedPreferences to store it and check about user logging or not:

```
private void saveUser(Users user) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("userId", user.getUserId());
        editor.putString("userName", user.getUserName());// or put anything you want in this with String type
        editor.putString("registration_id", user.getRegistrationId());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

You should use `editor.apply()` than `commit()` because `apply()` will run in your background thread and do not make any conflit about it and main thread.

Then you can get values from it like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
int id = preferences.getInt("userId", 0);// 0 is default values
```